# Postgres how to monitor database load

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

We're trying to make decisions about how to group/run database queries in Postgres, and trying to get a sense of of what the impact on our database is. For example, we have a background job that groups a bunch of operations into one to minimize the number of database queries. We'd like to split up some of this work, but we're not sure how best to monitor the impact on the database. If we're going to create 4000 extra queries spawned by separate jobs, how do we know what the impact is on Postgres? Do we just trust that everything is fine as long as the queries are relatively fast? Do we have to wait for the knock on effects of user facing timeouts? Is there a way to monitor resource consumption for Postgres?

We're using [Heroku Postgres](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) on one of the Premium tiers.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Monitoring

Answer (score 1):

Heroku Postgres injects statistical and operational information into the log drain for a given application. You can see a description of what's available in their documentation [here.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-metrics-logs). Additionally, some of these same metrics can be observed via a browser in your dashboard.

Finally, a large amount of data can be pulled for a database directly with the Heroku CLI. Some of this is baked into the CLI but there are also official plugins like [heroku-pg-extras](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras) that offer significantly more information.

A combination of these tools can give quite a bit of information about the health of your database at any given time and monitoring them over the course of any changes will inform you about the effect of the changes on the db.